# 'for' or 'in' before a period of time: For the past two decades VS In the past two decades

Tags: prepositions

1. For the past two decades, I have been truly impressed by the remarkable entrepreneurial spirit.
2. In the past two decades, I have been truly impressed by the remarkable entrepreneurial spirit.

Which is the proper one?

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. "Which is proper" (or correct or preferred and so on) is dependent on what you are trying to say; both might be acceptable, but mean different things, for example. Please [edit] to describe in other words the situation you are trying to express, as [context is always required](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439) to understand meaning. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As choster has stated, both are "proper", as both are grammatically correct. Indeed, the only differ in their choice of preposistion, a class of words used to express a relationship between two or more objects, or a thematic relationship between clauses in a sentence.

Note that regardless of the choice made, the prepositional phrase is being used to a indicate temporal (relating to time) relationship.

"For", as used here(it has *many* meanings), means "during the continuance or duration of". Thus, the sentence would indicate continuous impressing events over two decades.

"In", as used here(it has *many* meanings), means "within or occurrence during a period or limit of time". Thus, this sentence would indicate one or more impressing events occurred over two decades.

However, in the context of this sentence, and especially the scale of the time frame indicated, the distinction between the continuous and discrete events loses meaning. For example, we might imagine a movie being continuously filmed, but it would actually be photographing discrete photographic frames (24 for each second for a standard movie frame rate).

Therefore, as a (American) native speaker, I would use and interpret these two sentences interchangeably, and the distinction more of a personal vernacular choice, rather than a correct or incorrect choice.

Answer (score 2):

We use *for* with a period to express the whole range of that period: *for the last two years*; *for the next two years*.

When the sentence is negative, you can also use *in*: "I haven't seen him for two years" or "I haven't seen him in two years". To my (British) ears *in* sounds more American than British. This use is not usual when the sentence is positive.

Your "In the past two decades" is grammatical, and possible (though a bit unusual), but I would interpret it as "at some time or times in the last two decades" rather than "throughout the last two decades". (I think that is what choster was getting at with the question you replied rudely to).

Comment: As an American, your interpretation is correct. At least where I live and speak, "in" is used in positive sentences, referring to discrete events rather continuous ones. E.g. ""I've received three promotions in three years" vs "I've been employed for 3 years". This may be a cross-Atlantic thing...

Comment: No, @sharur, I agree with you. The bit I was saying seemed more American to me was 'in' with the negative, as in "I haven't seen him in three years". This is used here, but I think it is less natural than "for three years".